# Web method with XmlDocument as return type fails in SoapCore in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, asmx, soapcore

I am trying to host asmx type web service in asp.net core using SoapCore.

I have one web method as follows.

```
[OperationContract]
XmlDocument testProperties();
```

and concrete implementation for this as follows.

```
public XmlDocument testProperties()
{
    XmlDocument testProperties = new XmlDocument(); 
    testProperties.LoadXml("<test>abc</test>");
    return testProperties;
}
```

When I am trying to access this web method, it fails with following error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This element was named 'test' from namespace '' but should have been named 'TestPropertiesResult' from namespace ''.
```

Note: This issue only comes when method has return type as XmlDocument. If it is string or other simple data type, everything works perfectly.

Any lead would be helpful.

**Edit 1**

I have tried renaming test with TestPropertiesResult but that also does not solve anything. Only error message changes to

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This element was named 'TestPropertiesResult' from namespace '' but should have been named 'TestPropertiesResult' from namespace ''.
```

**Edit 2**

After further analysis in SoapCore, I could narrow down the root cause. 
This issue is coming when serialization happens of XmlDocument by XmlSerializer created as

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument), null, new Type[0], new XmlRootAttribute("dummynode"), "testnamespace");
```

I tried changing it to following

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
```

then it works but root element is missing. I can't change it. I can only change 
`XmlDocument`.

Comment: can you share with us how you are calling this method ?

Comment: calling it using postman.

Comment: Try changing the return type to a wrapper: public class Wrapper { public XmlDocument Data { get; } { set; } }.  It used to help back in the days of WSDL-services.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this documentation.

[What can be serialized using XMLSerializer ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization#items-that-can-be-serialized)

As per the documentation wrap the XMLDocument class as public member.

```
 public class Wrapper
 {
    public XmlDocument XmlDocument   { get; set; }
 }
 public static Wrapper testProperties()
 {
        XmlDocument testProperties = new XmlDocument();
        testProperties.LoadXml("<test>abc</test>");
        return new Wrapper { XmlDocument = testProperties };
 }
```

I hope this solves your problem.